# What does this code in ruby do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new here so please be gentle with me and I'm still just a newbie in programming and especially in ruby language.

This is a combo box and I want to know where it goes after I change it or what function it calls. Can you please tell me where it goes or what it does? thanks

```
<p><%= f.select :done_ratio, ((0..100).step(1).to_a.collect {|r| ["#{r} %", r] }), :required => @issue.required_attribute?('done_ratio') %></p>
```

Comment: This generates a static dropdown element. It does not go anywhere or call any function when you change selected value. Only when you submit the form, you'll see the selected choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is creating an [HTML `select` (dropdown) box](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), with the values: `0 %`, `1 %`, `2 %`, ..., `100 %`.

The field will be submitted as part of a form. It may or may not be a required field, depending on the value of `@issue.required_attribute?('done_ratio')`. (This is presumably a method in the `Issue` model, which can be found in `./app/models/issue.rb`.)

Breaking it down:

- `(0..100)` -- This is creating `Range` object, from 0 to 100 (inclusive).
- `.step(1)` -- This is not actually needed; you could delete it. But it's saying "step through the range 1 at a time" (which is the default anyway). It converts the `Range` to an `Enumerator`.
- `.to_a` -- This is not actually needed; you could delete it. This is converting the `Enumerator` to an `Array`.
- `.collect {|r| ["#{r} %", r] }` -- This is mapping the `Array` to a new list of arrays, like: `[["0 %", 0], ["1 %", 1], ..., ["100 %", 100]]`. (This method would also work perfectly fine on a `Range` or `Enumerator` object, since both classes include [this method from the `Enumerable` module](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect). Hence why the above two steps can both be removed!)
- `f.select :done_ratio, (...)` -- This is creating an HTML `select` element called `done_ratio`, with the above names/values.